# Difference between using AND and OR

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

i have 4 tables Participation,Lecturer_info,ScientificEvaluator,commision  each of them have a foreign key to the lecturer_info 
i want to search for lecturer and display all values from all tables

this select that does not return anything when I change the 'and' to 'or'. 
 It returns random values :

```
SELECT  Lecturer_Name, com_name ,Sicn_name ,Names_Of_Participations , pdf1 , pdf2,pdf3 
FROM Participation,Lecturer_info,ScientificEvaluator,commision  
where lecturer_fk = Lecturer_id and com_id = part_id  and Sicn_id = part_id 
    and Lecturer_Name = '% %'
```

Comment: Please add sample data and expected results.  Also, what do you mean by "random names"?

Comment: You will get better answers if you provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)  (MVCE). Without both code and example data it's harder for the Stack Overflow community to help you. Also, we cannot tell which tables the columns mentioned in your `WHERE` clause come from, so we won't be able to figure out what you're doing.

Comment: By far the biggest issue here is your join syntax. When you have AND those antiquated joins are inner joins. When you change them to OR you have completely disrupted the join logic. Fix your joins and this will likely no longer be an issue. https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins

Comment: Also, you should use aliases and ALWAYS specify which table a column belongs to in your queries. Since we don't know your database it is impossible to know what column goes with what table. I would also suggest you not do things like lecturer_fk. It is still the lecturer_id, just in a different table as a foreign key.

Comment: @squillman This means that many random values are returned

Comment: @squillman This means that many random values are returned

Comment: sir i have 4 tables each of them have a foreign kety to the lecturer_info

Comment: @Hassan The values are not "random". They are exactly the results you're asking for; they are just not the results you **want**.

Comment: sir i want to search for one not all of them

Comment: Maybe if you can post the table definitions and sample data along with the desired output this question could be saved. Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Answer (score 1):

With proper joins and some formatting your query might look like this.

```
SELECT l.Lecturer_Name
    , c.com_name 
    , se.Sicn_name 
    , p.Names_Of_Participations
    , pdf1
    , pdf2
    , pdf3
FROM Participation p
join Lecturer_info l on p.lecturer_fk = l.Lecturer_id
join ScientificEvaluator se on se.Sicn_id = p.part_id
join commision c on c.com_id = p.part_id
where l.Lecturer_Name = '% %'
```

But do you really have lecturer with a name of % %? Maybe you are trying to find lecturer names with a space in the name? That would be LIKE instead of =

If this query doesn't work right out of the box it is because I am coding blind.

Comment: it dosnt work sir nothing return

Comment: Again I am coding in the dark. I have no access to any of your tables and have no idea what you are trying to do. I would start by removing the where clause. Then evaluate the joins. Are they correct? Maybe you want left joins instead of inner joins?

Comment: sir i have 4 tables have a foreign key to the lecturer_info 
i want to search for lecturer form lecturer_info and display values form each tables

Answer (score 0):

The AND and OR operators are used to filter records based on more than one condition:

The AND operator displays a record if all the conditions separated by AND is TRUE.
The OR operator displays a record if any of the conditions separated by OR is TRUE.

Comment: sir i have edit my question pls anwser it